# Is it possible to navigate back in browser with watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm creating an automated tests that should navigate back a few steps.
Is it possible to do so in Watir??

I'm navigating to a resultlist page and want to go back to the start of my test just by clicking back (windows browser).
Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Watir::IE object, then #back is a method that does what you are looking for:

> http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Watir/IE.html#M000245

What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i tried to do it:

```
@site.ie.wait_until(1200) { |ie| ie.contains_text(/Sort after/) }
  2.times{@site.ie.back
}
```

Comment: The problem is solved.
ie.back works can be used, i didn'r put the code in right place.

Answer (score 0):

Example code that uses Watir's #back call (based on [the standard Wikipedia example](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/w/index.php?title=Watir&oldid=271482184#The_google_example)):

```
 require 'watir'
 test_site = 'http://www.google.com/'
 ie = Watir::IE.new
 ie.goto(test_site)
 ie.text_field(:name, "q").set("pickaxe")
 ie.button(:name, "btnG").click

 if ie.text.include?("Programming Ruby")  
   puts "Test Passed. Found the test string: 'Programming Ruby'."
 else
   puts "Test Failed! Could not find: 'Programming Ruby'." 
 end

 ie.back

 if ie.url == test_site
   puts "Test Passed. Returned to search page."
 else
   puts "Test Failed! URL is now #{ie.url}."
 end

 ie.close
```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can execute **JavaScript** using Watir.

```
@browser.execute_script('window.history.back();')
```